# Save a file and name it at the "Same" time (NAudio), improving the Accuracy

Tags: c#

I want to make a wavefile, and write data to it, and i want the filename to be time it began.

I know hot to write to the wave file using Wavewriter, and i know how to name it to the current time, the problem is however, to make it name the file as close as possible to the moment the audio is written.

Currently i have something like this:

```
    private void SaveReceivedAudio(string recieve)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                DialogResult result = folderBrowser.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    path = Path.GetFullPath(folderBrowser.SelectedPath) + (Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                    waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(path + recieve + "- " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-fff") + ".wav", new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 2));
                    waveWriterYour = new WaveFileWriter(path + Environment.UserName + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-fff") + ".wav", new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 2));
                    Record = true;
                    Recording.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    Recording.Text = "Recording";
                }
                else
                {
                    Record = false;
                    Recording.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    Recording.Text = "Not Recording";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SaveReceivedAudio: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

So as you can see i am clicking a button, choosing a directory, then it will create 2 files in this example at the moment it's created, then change Record to True.

However, this isn't accurate at all, it's probably fairly close, but it all depends on how it's executed.

Now, while i am saving another thread is on loop with the current audio data, which looks like this:

```
 private void RecordingQueueThread()
        {
            byte[] AudioData;
            byte[] AudioData2;
            while (connect)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Queue.TryTake(out AudioData, 300))
                    {
                        if (AudioData.Length == 0)
                            break;
                        else
                        {
                            if (Record)
                            {
                                waveWriter.Write(AudioData, 0, AudioData.Length);
                                waveWriter.Flush();
                                TestTimer += AudioData.Length;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (RecQueue.TryTake(out AudioData2, 300))
                    {
                        if (AudioData.Length == 0)
                            break;
                        else
                        {
                            if (Record)
                            {
                                waveWriterYour.Write(AudioData, 0, AudioData.Length);
                                waveWriterYour.Flush();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        MessageBox.Show("Recording: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Or well, maybe not in a loop, but there are 2 threads feedins this.

But as you can see, as there are 2 threads(or more) that work independetly, the audio will not be at the time of the Date i wrote earlier, it will be a bit later, and it can vary depending on, well, many thing, process time etc.

Which makes this a problem.

Best thing is if i can write the time exactly when the first data is written, i don't know how to do that however.

Any ideas?

Comment: So don't create your `WaveFileWriter` until the time when you really record, storing only a path when you get the `DialogResult`?

Comment: The problem is, how do i do that?
As it is in a loop, it will have to run by it all the time, and i have to be able to remake the Wavefile at command as well, so the bool "recording" doesn´t make justice.

Comment: If both threads are of the same function then: static int fileCreated = 0; if(fileCreated==0){ CreateFile(); fileCreated=1;}